# How to configure WCF with transport security behind a load balancer

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, load-balancing

I have a WCF service that will be configured to use transport security with a certificate. The service will sit behind a load balancer (F5).

The service certificate will be installed on the load balancer which will terminate the SSL session. I understand how to configure this---my question is whether or not I will be able to authenticate the client using the client certificate. Is this possible, or do I have to choose between client certificate authentication or load balancing?

Comment: Check out this [Michele Leroux Bustamante](http://www.devproconnections.com/author/1953/MicheleLerouxBustamante.aspx) article that covers this particular scenario: [http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/wcf-and-ssl-processing-load-balancers-122238](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/wcf-and-ssl-processing-load-balancers-122238)

Comment: Just to clarify, she doesn't address this scenario directly. However, she mentions the general case of non-Windows creds, which presumably includes client certs. See the "Asserting Security Capabilities" section that details lying to WCF about the presence of an SSL channel.